# Twitter Bootstrap 320andup Implementation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm creating a site using the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), but I've discovered that the media queries don't work on anything below IE9 (unfortunately my target browser). This deeming the whole reason I'm using the bootstrap (for the responsive scaling grid) pretty useless.

I was considering the implementation of [Andy Clarke's 320 and up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) responsive boilerplate within the bootstrap for the general better overall support on the IE side of things. (Or similar boilerplates)

Has anyone come across any examples of this being done online or on Github? (without the likes of SASS, HAML etc or being specifically created for a CMS). I have an idea of how I'm going to do it, but I'm not sure if it's a waste of time and I'd like to see if both tools can be pulled together successfully.

Comment: media queries [are supported by IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries), what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Hi @AndresIlich - yeah, IE9 is fine. IE7 & 8 is the problem :)

Comment: IE7 and 8 don't support media queries, but i think i got your question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fitzilla... I couldn't figure out how to add an additional comments, so I hope you find this.
I just checked [my website](http://yyyz.net/) in both IE7 & IE8 mode and both work. Do a view source on the initial page - you will see an additional hack for IE7 & IE8...

```
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Then check your includes against mine and see if they match. I believe the bootstrap-responsive has to be after the regular bootstrap css file.

Comment: Hey @gfw - Yes, I had that HTML5 shim included too. I was having trouble as I somehow ended up using a few different versions of the respond.js file... I used the one you had and it has suddenly decided to work. Great stuff, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In order for media queries to function in older browsers (IE7 and 8) you need to include a polyfill such as the [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) in the body of your document to support those techniques. Just noticed that the 320andup framework uses the same polyfill so you can easily include it in your bootstrap project.

Here is a test page that you can use to test the queries on IE7 and 8:

http://chrisjacob.github.com/Respond/

Comment: Cheers @AndresIlich, I was aware of the respond.js, I was uncertain whether the simple implementation of it in my code would have been enough. I assumed you had to do *another* sort of media query.

Comment: @fitzilla yeah, i misunderstood your question, thought you meant only IE9, but IE8 and below do not support media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Respond.js will make Bootstrap work for both IE7 & IE8 - at least using the developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) of IE9.   On my test site (http://ReactiveWebDesign.Net I include `respond.js` just before jQuery... the first included .js file

Comment: Thanks @Gfw. Good work. Just out of curiousity, why do you separate your site into so many individual stylesheets? Surely this will affect loading times? Or is this something do with the media queries? Are you using different stylesheets for each resolution or something?

Comment: The site is a work in progress so I haven't started combining. The 2 bootstrap css files could probably be combined as could the three site specific Site.css , mainNavWrapper.css & leftNavWrapper.css. Until the site is really complete it just makes it easier to keep them apart. The last 3 aren't even minimized, but eventually will be. The only other media queries used are for turning the menus into select statements for mobile devices.

Comment: Hey @Gfw, I've tried adding the respond.src.js to the file and I've included it just before the jquery tool. The layout of the website is still fixed when I check it in IE8. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?