# css3-mediaqueries.js VS respond.js

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries, polyfills

**[respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)** or **[css3-mediaqueries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)** ?

The official documentation, especially that of css3-mediaqueries.js, is sparse. Reading on SO, forums and [blogs](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/) I have summarized these pros and cons.

#### respond.js

Pros:

1. More reliable (? recommended by [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) , [Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) and [H5BP](http://www.initializr.com/) )
2. Lighter (4kb) and faster
3. Interpret mediaquery in any context (`<link>`, inline CSS, @import-ed CSS)

Cons:

1. Doesn't update on window resize
2. Supports only `min-width` and `max-width`
3. Doesn't support `em` units (huge weak point!)

#### css3-mediaqueries.js

Pros:

1. Reacts in real time (on resize too!)
2. Supports `em` units (really? anyone tested it?)

Cons:

1. Heavier (15kb) and slower
2. Interpret only inline CSS with a [explicitly declared media-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542823/media-queries-bootstrap-and-css3-mediaqueries-js-is-the-media-type-screen-h)
3. Lacks detailed documentation and the project seems abandoned

---

Does anyone have points to add to the list, or personal experiences to share, or a particular preference for one or the other script? If so, why?

Comment: It's worth stepping back and thinking why you need this. IE6-8 are run on desktop computers only. That means you know the screen size is going to be between 800x600 up to 1920x1080. However, bearing in mind that most users will be using a computer that shipped with IE6-8, we can assume that for most users it will be around 1024x768. So, they get a site that's say, 960px wide. Maybe it could be a little fluid if you like. Problem solved! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RichBradshaw. Indeed your feedback makes sense, i could let them interpret the "average desktop screen"  mediaquery. But where i live it's common to see old computers connected to much more recent screens, so the range of resolutions which still run on IE8 is very large (up to 1600x900 and over). For this and other reasons, i often find myself in the situation of _needing_ to use a polyfill...

Comment: Remember they might not be running full screen. But fair enough, if you have the data to back up the requirement. Remember responsiveness is just icing on the cake though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I created a test page, including [Mediatizr](https://github.com/pyrsmk/mediatizr) too.

If anyone is interested, [here's the test page](http://gionaf.com/playground/mq-fallback/), and these are the [results](http://gionaf.com/playground/mq-fallback/results.html) (tested on IE8 and IE7).

---

### css3-mediaqueries.js

#### Pros

1. Supports `min`, `max` and `min+max` mediaqueries
2. Supports `px` and `em` values
3. Reacts on window resize
4. Elaborates on-page CSS (`<style>`) and external stylesheets

#### Cons

1. Doesn't support `width` mediaquery
2. Doesn't elaborate `<link media="screen and ...">` nor `@import`ed stylesheet

---

### respond.js

#### Pros

1. Supports `min`, `max` and `min+max` mediaqueries
2. Supports `px` and `em` values
3. Reacts on window resize
4. Elaborates external stylesheets only

#### Cons

1. Doesn't support `width` mediaquery
2. Doesn't elaborate on-page CSS, `<link media="screen and ...">` nor `@import`ed stylesheets
3. It may cause a javascript error when combined with jQuery `on load` events, to solve it you need to place the script at the end of the page

---

### mediatizr.js

Simply..doesn't work

---

In the end I opted for **css-mediaqueries.js**, conditionally loaded with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: I used mediatizr successfully after trying respond and having it not work appropriately.

Comment: From memory css3-mediaqueries.js supports cm which respond.js doesn't.

Comment: I had some problem with respons.js all page random was white so i switch to css3-mediaqueries.js, but then CPU go to 99% and crash IE8. Create modern website is painful with back compatibility

Answer (score -2):

The point is probably moot now. I have developed a pure Javascript framework that generates and manages media queries. It works with all browsers and operating systems. It's footprint is less than 500 characters. You can see it working here:
ieee-ac.org.